# Which method is better in order to get the direction?

Tags: android, gps, sensors, geography

I want to get the direction in Android. There are two methods.

One is the orientation sensor. The value of data value[0] is the azimuth: angle between the magnetic north direction and the y-axis, around the z-axis (0 to 359). 0=North, 90=East, 180=South, 270=West.

The other is GPS. I can use android.location.Location.getBearing() to get the direction of travel in degrees East of true North.

I use both of these methods at the same time, and find the values differs a lot. For example, the value of orientation sensor is 20, while the value of the GPS bearing is 340. Why are there differences? Which is better?

BTW, is the difference related to the difference between the magnetic north and the true north? In geography, they are not same.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the difference is because GPS uses the geographical North/South Pole rather than the magnetic ones. The further north you are, the bigger the difference is to where you are. The GPS satellite positions need to be absolute, and using a fluctuating point of reference like the magnetic poles is a big no-no.

Which one you should use: I would go with GPS when moving, and compass when standing still.

Comment: Good explanation. Got the difference!!

Answer (score 2):

The magnetic sensors show the magnetic heading of the phone, i.e. where it is pointed to wrt. magnetic north.
The GPS indicated the bearing of the phone wrt. true north, i.e. the direction of travel or the true track.
If the phone is moving on the agonic line (the line where the magnetic variation is zero, it moves through in France for example) and if the phone pointing in the direction of travel they should be the same (plus/minus accuracy of the sensor).